# Hello world with android but without eclipse

Tags: android

I am pretty sure that I once stumbled upon a link that showed how to create a *hello world* application *without* eclipse, but I can't find that link anymore. It certainly needs not be a *hello world* application, but it would be nice if someone could point me to somewhere that explains the steps needed to create an application without eclipse.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well, the best place to find would be the android docs.

Check this link out: http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/index.html

It has, for instance in the category "Managing Projects" and "Building and Running" links for

- "From Eclipse with ADT"

but also for

- **"From the Command Line"**

There is enough information about how to develop without Eclipse :D

Answer (score 6):

Google's [Hello World tutorial](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/hello-world.html) has a section on [managing projects from the command line](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/projects/projects-cmdline.html).

Answer (score 3):

Maybe what you were looking at was the maven android plugin (which is awesome btw) and the [page on the archetypes](https://github.com/akquinet/android-archetypes/wiki) it has. So you could just use this snippet here:

```
 mvn archetype:generate \
  -DarchetypeArtifactId=android-quickstart \
  -DarchetypeGroupId=de.akquinet.android.archetypes \
  -DarchetypeVersion=1.0.5 \
  -DgroupId=your.company \
  -DartifactId=my-android-application
```

And that will do the trick for you.

P.S. If you read the docs you can specify the target SDK (or min SDK if you will) by adding the '-Dplatform=' option to that command.